# Dash app connections to AWS postgres DB VERY SLOW

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I've created a live-updating dash app connected to a public facing AWS Postgres database. I've put db connection within my callback so it updates, but I find that it takes a long long time to retrieve data and create the graph, such that if the interval time is reduced to 10 seconds or less, no graph loads at all. I've tried to store the data in dcc.store but the initial load still takes a very long time. My abbreviated code is written below. I'm assuming the lag time is from the engine connecting to the database, because I am only reading a few rows and columns. Is there anyway to speed this up?

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, func, Date, ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[BS], suppress_callback_exceptions=True, update_title=None)
server=app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Store(id='time', storage_type='session'),
dcc.Store(id='blood_pressure', storage_type='session'),

html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=False), className='w-100'),
        html.Div(id= "testing"),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update-BP',
            interval=30000,
            n_intervals=0
        )]), width={"size": 10, "offset": 0.5}),
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Output('blood_pressure', 'data'),
    dash.dependencies.Output('time', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update-BP', 'n_intervals')],
    Input('live-graph', 'relayoutData'),
)
def update_graph_scatter_1(n):
   
            trace = []
            blood_pressure = []
            time = []
           

            engine = create_engine("postgresql://username:password@address:5432/xxxxx", echo=True, future=True)
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()
            Base = automap_base()
            Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
            User = Base.classes.users
            Datex = Base.classes.data

            for instance in session.query(Datex).filter(Datex.user_id  == 3).filter(Datex.date_time == 'Monday,Apr:26'):
                blood_pressure.append([instance.systolic, instance.mean, instance.diastolic])
                time.append(instance.time)
               
            for i in range(0, len(blood_pressure)):
                trace.append(go.Box(y=blood_pressure[i],
                                    x=time[i],
                                    line=dict(color='#6a92ff'),
                                    hoverinfo='all'))
           
            fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)

            def append_trace():

                for i in range(0, len(trace)):
                    fig.append_trace(trace[i], 1, 1)

                
            append_trace()

          
            return fig, blood_pressure, hr,
```

Comment: Engine creation and automapping should only be done once, if possible.

Comment: I'd recommend against including the DB_URI in this post, for security purposes. Switch it out with an environment variable. (We'll use our imaginations as to what that db connection is).

Comment: And I agree with @snakecharmerb --> this app could benefit from modularization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase performance in your app in the following ways:

**Non-programming methods:**

1. If your app is deployed on AWS, ensure your app is connecting to your database over private IP. This reduces the number of networks your data has to traverse and will result in significantly lower latency.
2. Ensure your virtual machine has enough RAM. (If you're loading 2GB of data to a machine with 1GB available RAM, you're going to see the IO hit disk before loading to your program.)

**Programming methods:**

1. Modularize connecting to your database, and only do it once. This decreases the overhead required to reserve resources and authenticate connecting to the database

```py
import os

class DbConnection:
    """Use this class to connect to your database within a dashapp"""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.DB_URI = os.environ.get('DB_URI', kwargs.get('DB_URI'))
        self.echo = kwargs.get('echo', True)
        self.future = kwargs.get('future', True)

        # Now create the engine
        self.engine = create_engine(self.DB_URI, echo=self.echo, future=self.self)
        # Make the session maker
        self.session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

    @property
    def session(self):
        """Return a session as a property"""
        return self.session_maker()


# -------------------------------------------

# In your app, instantiate the database connection
#  and map your base
my_db_connection = DbConnection()  # provide kwargs as needed
session = my_db_connection.session  # necessary to assign property to a variable

# Map the classes
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(my_db_connection.engine, reflect=True)
User = Base.classes.users
Datex = Base.classes.data
```

2. Cache frequently queried data. Unless your data is massive and dramatically varying, you should expect better performance from loading the data from disk (or RAM) on your machine, than over the network from your database.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def get_blood_pressure(session, user_id, date):
    """returns blood pressure for a given user for a given date"""
    blood_pressure, time = [], []
    query = session.query(Datex)\
        .filter(Datex.user_id == 3)\
        .filter(Datex.date_time == 'Monday,Apr:26')
    
    # I like short variable names when interacting with db results
    for rec in query:
        time.append(rec.time)
        blood_pressure.append([rec.systolic, rec.mean, rec.diastolic])
    
    # finally
    return blood_pressure, time
```

3. Putting them all together, your callback should be a lot quicker

```
def update_graph_scatter_1(n):
    # I'm not sure how these variables will be assigned
    # but you'll figure it out
    blood_pressure, time = get_blood_pressure(session=session, user_id=user_id, date='Monday,Apr:26')
    
    # Create new traces
    for i in range(0, len(blood_pressure)):
        trace.append(go.Box(
            y=blood_pressure[i],
            x=time[i],
            line=dict(color='#6a92ff'),
            hoverinfo='all'
        ))
        
        # Add to subplots   
        fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
        for i in range(0, len(trace)):
            fig.append_trace(trace[i], 1, 1)
          
    return fig, blood_pressure, time
```

4. Lastly, it looks like you're recreating your graph objects each update. This is a heavy operation. I'd recommend updating the graph's data instead. I know this is possible, since I've done this in the past. But it looks like the solution is not-trivial, unfortunately. Perhaps an item for a later response or follow up Q.

---

**Further reading:** https://dash.plotly.com/performance

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I just need a little clarification regarding the **kwargs . If the DB_URI is saved as an environmental variable: ''DB_URI = "postgresql://username:password@address:5432/xxxxx"'. I'm uncertain what **kwargs are needed. And as an aside future = self.self should be self.future? Thanks again

Comment: `kwargs` allow you to override the env variable with class supplied values. This is best practice for writing durable software. Ex: you could be using a secret manager and wish to set the value through that sort of service. @RobertMarciniak

Comment: To your 2nd point: `future` is the arg param, `self.future` is the value which was set earlier (`self.future = kwargs.get('future', True)`)

Comment: I hope it's not too late to ask a followup question. You're suggestions were implemented and wow! What a difference. Thank you. I'm looking into extendData property to prevent recreating the graph object as you suggested. The only had issue I've had was with @lru_cache(). When the callback is triggered the get_blood_pressure function does not update new rows from the DB. However, when I removed it. All works well. However, I am interested in incorporating it. Any ideas what may be going on? Thank you.